# Restarting program in python

Tags: python

I've been trying to make a Tamagotchi clone in python recently, but I need help as I just can't figure out how to make the code go back to the start after a certain point. I tried the

```
while == True:
```

kind of method, and I understand it I just don't know how to get it working with my code. Below is my code - It is quite long so please excuse the length. I commented it pretty thoroughly and it should be easy to read. Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

```
# Modules
import os  # Used for cls function - clean screen
import time  # Used for delaying messages etc.
import sys

# Pet details
running = True

petType = ""
petName = ""
activity = ""

# Pet well being
pet = [60, 60, 0]  # 0 = energy 1 = happiness 2 = training
# Loop counter
i = 0



#
# Animal Art for the activity loop and other parts
#
def cat():  # Stores cat ASCII art - credit to 'jgs' - https://user.xmission.com/~emailbox/ascii_cats.htm
    print('''|
| \    /_
|  )  ( ')
| (  /  )
|  \(__)|
|''')


def bird():  # Cat ASCII - credit to 'as' - http://chris.com/ascii/index.php?art=animals/birds
    print('''|
|   >\_/<
|  _\*v*/_
|  \\   //
| ===="====
|    /^\
|
|''')


def bunny():  # Bunny ASCII - credit to 'Felix Lee' - http://www.chris.com/ascii/index.php?art=animals/rabbits
    print('''|
|  /\ /|
|  \ V /
|  | "")
|  / ` |
|  /   \)
| (__\_\)
|''')


def dog():  # Dog ASCII - credit 'jgs' - http://www.chris.com/ascii/index.php?art=animals/dogs
    print('''|
|          .-._
|         {_}^ )o
|  {\_______//~`
|  (         )
|  /||~~~~~||\,
| |_\.\_    \.\_\_
|''')


def mouse():  # Mouse ASCII - credit 'jgs' - http://www.chris.com/ascii/index.php?art=animals/rodents/mice
    print('''|
|          (\-.
|          / _`>
|  _)     / _)=
| (      / _/
|  `-.__(___)_
|''')


###################

# 'Sleep' are made to be easier to write than 'time.sleep(1)
def sleep():
    time.sleep(1)


# Clears the console
def cls():
    os.system('cls')


# Shows the pet's statistics from user's previous inputs like name, type, energy etc.
def printStats():
    sleep()
    print("|-----------------------------")
    print("| " + petName + "'s Stats: ")
    if petType == "Cat":
        cat()
    elif petType == "Bird":
        bird()
    elif petType == "Bunny":
        bunny()
    elif petType == "Dog":
        dog()
    elif petType == "Mouse":
        mouse()
    print("| Breed: " + petType)

    print("| Energy: " + str(pet[0]))
    print("| Happiness: " + str(pet[1]))
    print("| Training: " + str(pet[2]))
    print("|-----------------------------")


def limiter():
    if pet[0] >= 100:
        pet[0] = 100
    elif pet[1] >= 100:
        pet[1] = 100
    elif pet[2] >= 100:
        pet[2] = 100
#
#
# Introduction Message and start of the actual game
#
#

print("""|-------------------
| Welcome to Tamagotchi!
|-------------------""")
sleep()
print("""Please choose a type of pet from the list below: (enter a,b,c,d or e)
a. Bird
b. Bunny
c. Cat
d. Dog
e. Mouse
""")

# Getting pet's type and processing it
while i == 0:
    sleep()
    petType = input("Which one would you like?: ")
    if petType == "a":
        petType = "Bird"
        sleep()
        print("You chose a " + petType)
        sleep()
        print("Congratulations! Your new pet is ready.")
        bird()
        sleep()
        break  # stops loop
    elif petType == "b":
        petType = "Bunny"
        sleep()
        print("You chose a " + petType)
        sleep()
        print("Congratulations! Your new pet is ready.")
        bunny()
        sleep()
        break  # stops loop
    elif petType == "c":
        petType = "Cat"
        sleep()
        print("You chose a " + petType)
        sleep()
        print("Congratulations! Your new pet is ready.")
        cat()
        sleep()
        break  # stops loop
    elif petType == "d":
        petType = "Dog"
        sleep()
        print("You chose a " + petType)
        sleep()
        print("Congratulations! Your new pet is ready.")
        dog()
        sleep()
        break  # stops loop
    elif petType == "e":
        petType = "Mouse"
        sleep()
        print("You chose a " + petType)
        sleep()
        print("Congratulations! Your new pet is ready.")
        mouse()
        sleep()
        break  # stops loop
    else:
        print("ERROR: That's not a valid pet type.")  # Error message
        sleep()
        petType = input("Which one would you like?: ")
        continue  # Continues the loop

# Name loop
while i == 0:
    petName = input("Please choose a name for your new pet: ")
    if petName.isnumeric():
        print("ERROR: That is not a valid name. Please use only letters.")
        petName = input("Please choose a name for your new pet: ")
        continue  # continues loop
    elif len(petName) >= 25:  # Checks if the entry for name is too long
        print("ERROR: Please do not enter more than 25 characters.")
        petName = input("Please choose a name for your new pet: ")
        continue  # continues loop
    elif petName == "":
        print("ERROR: Please enter a name")
        petName = input("Please choose a name for your new pet: ")
        continue  # continues loop
    else:
        print(petName + "! That's a nice name")
        break  # stops loop

cls()
# Activity loop
while i == 0:
    activity = input("Do you want to (f)eed, (p)lay, (s)leep or (t)rain?: ")
    if activity.isdigit():
        print("ERROR: That is not a valid activity.")
        activity = input("Do you want to (f)eed, (p)lay, (s)leep or (t)rain?: ")
    elif activity == "f":
        pet[0] += 5
        print("")
        print("You fed " + petName + ". +5 Energy.")
        limiter()
        printStats()
        time.sleep(2)
        cls()
    elif activity == "p":
        pet[1] += 10
        pet[0] -= 10
        print("")
        print("You played with " + petName + ". -10 Energy, +10 Happiness.")
        limiter()
        printStats()
        time.sleep(2)
        cls()
    elif activity == "s":
        pet[0] += 20
        pet[1] -= 5
        print("")
        print("You decided to let " + petName + " sleep. +20 Energy, -5 Happiness.")
        limiter()
        printStats()
        time.sleep(2)
        cls()
    elif activity == "t":
        pet[2] += 10
        pet[0] -= 10
        pet[1] -= 5
        print("")
        print("You decided to train " + petName + ". -10 Energy, -5 Happiness, +10 Training.")
        limiter()
        printStats()
        time.sleep(2)
        cls()
    elif pet[0] <= 0:
        print(petName + " died because he reached 0 energy :(")
        break
    elif pet[1] <= 0:
        print(petName + " ran away because he was unhappy :(")
        break
    elif pet[2] == 100:
        print("Congratulations! " + petName + " has reached 100 training!")

    else:
        print("ERROR: That is not a valid activity.")
```

I need to have the code restart after all three of these if statements (so after it reaches 0 energy, happiness, or if the pet reaches 100 training)

```
    elif pet[0] <= 0:
    print(petName + " died because he reached 0 energy :(")
    break
elif pet[1] <= 0:
    print(petName + " ran away because he was unhappy :(")
    break
elif pet[2] == 100:
    print("Congratulations! " + petName + " has reached 100 training!")
```

Thank you very much in advance :)
Marcell

Comment: Please edit your code down to only the parts that are necessary to reproduce the problem (for example, your issue could probably be reproduced with fewer than five different kinds of pet).

Comment: I must agree with TigerhawkT3.  It's too bad because I like your pets ;)  BTW, `while == True:` is not valid syntax; it should be `while True:`

Comment: Sorry about that. I'm glad you enjoyed the pets :p

Answer (score 1):

```
while True:

#
#
# Introduction Message and start of the actual game
#
#

  print("""|-------------------
  | Welcome to Tamagotchi!
  |-------------------""")

#[...]
  # Activity loop
  while True:
  #[...]

    elif pet[0] <= 0:
        print(petName + " died because he reached 0 energy :(")
        break
    elif pet[1] <= 0:
        print(petName + " ran away because he was unhappy :(")
        break
    elif pet[2] == 100:
        print("Congratulations! " + petName + " has reached 100 training!")

    else:
        print("ERROR: That is not a valid activity.")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea, you do in fact need a `while True:`. Put that line where you want the program to go back to after the pet dies. You can then use a break statement like you already are to break out of the first loop and go back to the top to make a new pet.